# Custom intent crashing my app

Tags: android-intent, android-toast

I am working on an app (just a little fun project for my self, I'm not putting it on the Play Store) that will send a toast. My end goal is to have a shell command to send a toast. I don't care how I get these results, I just want it to work.

I'm thinking I am going to have the shell command sending an intent to my app. I am using a custom intent:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.tylerr147.toast" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
</intent-filter>
```

When I use `adb shell am start -a "com.tylerr147.toast" --es "android.intent.extra.TEXT" "toasty" -t "text/plain"` to start it, my app crashes.

Here is my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.tylerr147.intenttoast" >
<application android:allowBackup="true"
android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
android:label="@string/app_name"
android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity android:name=".handler" >
        <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="com.tylerr147.toast" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
</intent-filter>
</activity>
</application>
</manifest>
```

And my handler.java

```
package com.tylerr147.intenttoast;
import android.app.*;
import android.content.*;
import android.net.*;
import android.os.*;
import android.widget.*;
import java.util.*;
import android.util.*;

public class handler extends Activity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String action = intent.getAction();
        String type = intent.getType();
        handleSendText(intent);
    }
    public void handleSendText(Intent intent)
    {
        try{ String sharedText = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
        if (sharedText != null) {
            // Update UI to reflect text being shared
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), sharedText, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        } catch(Exception e) {
    Log.e("Boked", e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
adb shell am broadcast -a "com.tylerr147.toast" --es "android.intent.extra.TEXT" "toasty" -t "text/plain"
```

instead of

```
adb shell am start -a "com.tylerr147.toast" --es "android.intent.extra.TEXT" "toasty" -t "text/plain"
```

replace start with broadcast.

hope it works.

Comment: Although it didn't crash this time, it also didn't do the toast.